# How to get name of country based on id?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a table where I'm saving my records id of languages (`language_skills_selected`). Now, I need to get name for every item. I saved names in table `language_skills`.

Here is my variables and dd for everyone:

**`$data['user_test'] = DB::table('language_skills_selected')->where('user_id', $id)->get();`**

```
Language: 22 - Level: Intermediate 

Language: 41 - Level: Beginner 

Language: 13 - Level: Expert 

Language: 35 - Level: Expert 

Language: 23 - Level: Intermediate
```

And here I have the variable with names : 
`$data['language_skills'] = \App\LanguageSkill::lists('language_skill','id');`

```
{"1":"Albanian","2":"Arabic","3":"Bengali","4":"Belarus","5":"Bulgarian","6":"Czech","7":"Chinese","8":"Korean","9":"Croatian","10":"Danish","11":"Hebraic","12":"English","13":"Estonian","14":"Finnish","15":"French","16":"German","17":"Greek","18":"Hindi","19":"Icelandic","20":"Italian","21":"Japanese","22":"Latvian","23":"Lithuanian","24":"Macedonian","25":"Hungarian","26":"Norwegian","27":"Dutch","28":"Persian","29":"Polish","30":"Portuguese","31":"Romanian","32":"Russian","33":"Serbian","34":"Slovak","35":"Slovene","36":"Spanish","37":"Swedish","38":"Thai","39":"Turkish","40":"Ukrainian","41":"Other"}
```

So, instead of these id, I need to have Name of language - ex: `Language: Bulgarian - Level : Expert`

Comment: Please post the exact table structure. You have two tables, `language_skills_selected` and `language_skills`, right? What are the column names of each? You can use a `join` to get your result. If I know the column structure, I can help you out with the join

Comment: Sorry, so in `language_skills_selected` I have - `id`, `user_id` and `language_skills`( Here are id) . In `language_skills` I have `id` and `language_skills` ( here are the names ) . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
$data['user_test'] = DB::table('language_skills_selected')
     ->select("language_skills.language_skill")
     ->join("language_skills","language_skills_selected.language_skills","=","language_skills.id")
     ->where('language_skills_selected.user_id', $id)->get();
```

Comment: With this code I get this error : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'language_skills.language_skills' in 'field list' (SQL: select `language_skills`.`language_skills` from `language_skills_selected` inner join `language_skills` on `language_skills_selected`.`language_skills` = `language_skills`.`id` where `language_skills_selected`.`user_id` = 548)

Comment: please provide language_skills table field list

Comment: updated answer  `language_skills` =>` language_skill` in `select` function

Comment: if same as name in `language_skills_selected` table then also update `language_skills_selected.language_skills` to `language_skills_selected.language_skill` in `join` function

Comment: With this update I get : Undefined property: stdClass::$language_skills (View: /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/resources/views/profile/language_skill.blade.php) (View: /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/resources/views/profile/language_skill.blade.php)

Comment: query works? this error in view file so please check query result

Comment: Yes, it works at dd, I get every language correctly. But do you know how to fix last problem? Here is the problem  <p>Language: {{$usr->language_skills}} - Level: .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206004/discussion-between-andrew-and-kelvin-kantaria).

Comment: use  `{{$usr->language_skill}}` not `{{$usr->language_skills}}`

Answer (score 1):

### Naming conventions

First of all, I would change the strucuture to use conventional Laravel naming.
It also helps others to better understand relations in your table.

You already use `id` as your auto-increment primary key, which is good.
If you then reference another table through a foreign key, use the singular table name, followed by `_id`.
So your `language_skills_selected` table structure becomes

**language_skills_selected**
`id` int primary
`user_id` int foreign key (users table)
`language_skill_id` int foreign key (language_skills table)

**language_skills**
`id` int primary
`name` string (the name, singular, as it will only have one name in it)

I would rename the column `language_skills` to `name`, as the table name already suggests that each entry in the table will be a language_skill. The column name should be more descriptive of what it actually holds, in your case `language_skills` column holds the name. So then you might as well name the column that way.

### Joining tables

In Laravel, you can use the **Query Builder** [(see here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database)) to build queries, or you can use **Eloquent Models** ([see here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent)). I highly suggest you read through both parts of the documentation extensively.
It is a vital part of the framework and choosing when to use what depends on your use case.

Now finally to your solution. If you have changed the column names, you can write a join statement between two tables like this:

```
$data['user_test'] = DB::table('language_skills_selected')
    ->join('language_skills', 'language_skills_selected.language_skill_id', '=', 'language_skills.id')
    ->where('user_id', $id)
    ->get();
```

You will then have a joined result, where you can access the name of the language_skill as well.

I would also suggest you read in general more about MySQL, as it is good basis know how before diving into the framework. Lookup MySQL joins, and read material [like this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
1 -> query for Get All skills

$data['user_test'] = DB::table('language_skills_selected')->where('user_id', $id)->get();

2 -> Query For language_skills Name
$data['language_skills'] = \App\LanguageSkill::where('id',$data['user_test']['language_skills])->get('language_skills');

3 -> Set Name instead of ID
$data['user_test']['language_skills'] = $data['language_skills'];
```

You can use foreach Loop;
I suggest to change the names of variable